# Automount ext4 format thumb drive via NFS on a raspberry pi in cluster with fstab fails on reboot

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, mount, nfs, reboot

I am trying to automount (on reboot) an NFS thumb drive onto another raspberry pies in a cluster using `fstab`.

I have tried all the solutions on how to auto mount NFS drive on reboot using `fstab`

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347996/rpi4-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-nfs-drive-not-mounting-on-boot

- `systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`
- `x-systemd.automount`
- `x-systemd.mount-timeout=5`
- `x-systemd.device-timeout=5`

2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405231/unable-to-mount-nfs-on-ubuntu-22-04

- `auto,vers=3`
- `_netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=10,timeo=14,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min`

but none of them auto mounts nfs drive after a reboot. I have to use `mount -a` after a reboot.

I am using the following distribution on all raspberry pies:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

The current `fstab` entry

`rpi1:/home/pi/cloud /home/pi/cloud nfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=5,_netdev 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and non hassel solution I found is to install `nfs-common` package on the clients.